# Is it possible to slipstream the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

From what I've read, [VS 2008 SP1 and Team Foundation Server SP1 packages are traditional service packs that require you to first install the original versions before you will be able to install the SP](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/08/11/8849574.aspx).

Is there a way, supported or not, to slipstream the install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [MSDN forum post](https://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3337363&SiteID=1) in which an MSFTie indicates it will be possible and that details are forthcoming.  Another poster is relaying results of her almost-successful attempt.  Looks like this will be doable soon.

Related: [how to slipstream Team Foundation Server 2008 SP1 (TFS 2008 SP1)](http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs/000444.html)

Comment: This is a false solution, I spent a *lot* of time wondering why Visual Studio installation was bad (you discover after a while!). Sad, but the there is no solution. If someone does not trust me it should just run a file compare to check (also do not forget to check the registry)

Comment: @Sorin What solution? All this answer says is that it /might/ be possible eventually.

Answer (score 3):

**Here are the steps for slipstreaming visual studio 2008 with service pack 1**

1. Consider you have visual studio 2008 ISO file or DVD mounted on G: drive. If your drive letter is different then dont worry. I will get back to this in step 4.
2. You have enough space say in HDD in partition say D: of about 8GB.
3. Extract the visual studio 2008 service pack 1 to D:\VS\SP1 folder
4. Copy the below commands to a batch file and name it "integrate.bat" and place it in "D:\VS\" folder. If your DVD drive letter is different, then suitable modify the G: in the batch file with the corresponding drive letter.

   ```
   ::Extract the original visual studio 2008 installation to directory VS2k8WithSP1.
   msiexec.exe /a "g:\vs_setup.msi" TARGETDIR="%CD%\VS2k8WithSP1"

   ::Copy some file to make slipstream integration successful.
   copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\1033\*.chm" "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\"

   ::Extract each .msp files to directory VS2k8WithSP1.
   msiexec.exe /a "%cd%\VS2k8WithSP1\vs_setup.msi" /p "%cd%\SP1\vs90sp1\VS90sp1-KB945140-X86-ENU.msp"
   msiexec.exe /a "%cd%\VS2k8WithSP1\vs_setup.msi" /p "%cd%\SP1\vs90sp1\VC90sp1-KB947888-x86-enu.msp"
   msiexec.exe /a "%cd%\VS2k8WithSP1\vs_setup.msi" /p "%cd%\SP1\vs90sp1\VC90sp1-KB948484-x86_x64-enu.msp"
   msiexec.exe /a "%cd%\VS2k8WithSP1\vs_setup.msi" /p "%cd%\SP1\vs90sp1\VC90sp1-KB948560-x86_IA64-enu.msp"


   ::Copy the product key file
   copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Setup\Setup.sdb"

   ::Copy the setup bootstrapper files
   copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\CSetupMM\*.*" "VS2k8WithSP1\Setup"

   ::Copy VC runtime files
   md VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\VCRuntimes
   copy SP1\vs90sp1\vc_*runtime.exe VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\VCRuntimes

   ::copy SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard
   copy SP1\vs90sp1\SqlPubWizInstaller.exe VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SqlPub

   ::copy SQL Server 2008 Management Objects and SQL Server System CLR Types configuration.
   md VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SMO
   copy SP1\vs90sp1\SharedManagementObjects.msi VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SMO
   copy SP1\vs90sp1\SQLSysClrTypes.msi VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SMO

   ::copy SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 English with the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 Design Tools English.
   copy /Y SP1\vs90sp1\SSCERuntime-enu.msi VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SSCE
   copy /Y SP1\vs90sp1\SSCEVSTools-enu.msi VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SSCE

   ::Extract the dotnetfx35.exe manually to a %tmp% folder. Copy all files and subdirectories from %tmp%\wcu\dotnetframework to vs2k8WithSP1\wcu\dotnetframework and overwrite files
   ::Sorry I could not able to automate this step as /extract option is disabled in the dotnetfx35.exe file.
   ```
5. Go to command prompt and navigate to "D:\VS\".
6. With "D:\VS" as the current directory execute the integrate.bat batch file. This will take approximately 1hr. So relax and work in parallel with other stuff.
7. After the batch file executes completely, extract the dotnetfx35.exe manually to a "D:\VS\tmp folder". Copy and overwrite all files and subdirectories from "D:VS\tmp\wcu\dotnetframework" to "D:\VS\vs2k8WithSP1\wcu\dotnetframework"
8. Now you have successfully slipstreamed the visual studio 2008 with service pack1. Now D:\VS\VS2k8WithSP1 folder contains the slipstreamed copy of visual studio 2008. Now you can delete ISO files (if you have) and any other files or folders other than D:\VS\VS2k8WithSP1.

Answer (score 2):

The steps posted above work, with some minor adjustments:

```
::Copy some file to make slipstream integration successful. 
copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\1033*.chm" "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\"
```

I recommend copying the multiple files in the 1033 folder manually.  There's only two of them.  There seems to be some confusion surrounding the use of asterisks (*) in batch files.

I also recommend copying the following files manually:

```
::Copy the setup bootstrapper files 
copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\CSetupMM*.*" "VS2k8WithSP1\Setup"
```

And for the SQL Publishing Wizard 1.3:

```
::copy SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 
copy SP1\vs90sp1\SqlPubWizInstaller.exe VS2k8WithSP1\wcu\SqlPub
```

Visual Studio 2008 setup will tell you at the end of the installation that this component failed to install.

```
VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.3 is not installed.
```

However, upon checking the Event Viewer as well as the Visual Studio setup log, this is **not true**.  All indications say it installed successfully.  And the true test of actually using the wizard, works well.

Apart from that, this tutorial works great!

Many thanks to the author(s).

Answer (score 0):

::Copy some file to make slipstream integration successful. copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\1033*.chm" "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\"

there is a error here, should be:

::Copy some file to make slipstream integration successful. copy "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\1033\*.chm" "VS2k8WithSP1\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\"

"\" must be doubled in this case, coz one of them used as escape character of "*"